# How to replicate this for-loop using forEach()?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, ecmascript-6, foreach, sum

How would one replicate this for-loop using 'Array.prototype.forEach() ' ?

```js
const getSums = (arr) => {
  let result = []
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    result.push(arr[i] - arr[i + 1])
  }
  return result
}

console.log(getSums([100, 99, 99, 100]))
```

expected output: `[1, 0, -1]`

Comment: It's a pity that javascript's stdlib doesn't seem to have a windowing function (`each_cons` in ruby, `windows` in rust)

Answer (score 2):

`forEach` can give you an index of element. You could use that.

```js
const getSums = (arr) => {
    let result = []
    arr.forEach((el, i) => {
        if (i < arr.length - 1) result.push(el - arr[i + 1])
    })
    return result
}
console.log(getSums([100, 99, 99, 100]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the index, you could save the previous value outside of the loop.

```js
const getSums = (arr) => {
    let result = []
    let prev = null;
    arr.forEach(el => {
        if (prev) {
          result.push(prev - el);
        }
        prev = el;
    })
    return result
}
console.log(getSums([100, 99, 99, 100]))
```

Answer (score 0):

A pure FP solution is somewhat bulky, because JS doesn't have built-in `zip`, but here you go

```js
let zip = (a, b) => a.map((_, i) => [a[i], b[i]])

a = [100, 99, 99, 100]

deltas = zip(a.slice(0, -1), a.slice(1)).map(([x, y]) => x - y)

console.log(deltas)
```

Comment: an `each_n_consecutive_elements` would be more useful than `zip`, but JS doesn't have this one either.

Answer (score 0):

It's like an `Array.forEach`, with a some addintions :  [array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method
like initialize your array

```js
const getSums = arr => arr.reduce((result,current,i,{[i+1]:next}) =>
  {                                               //       next = arr[i+1]
  if (!isNaN(next))             // if next is not a number 
    result.push(current -next); // !isNaN(undefined) == false
  return result
  }
  , []) // initialize -> result=[]
  
console.log('getSums',JSON.stringify(getSums([100, 99, 99, 100])))


//OneLine Code:
const deltas =A=>A.reduce((r,c,i,{[i+1]:n})=>(!isNaN(n)?r[i]=c-n:'',r),[])

console.log('deltas', JSON.stringify(deltas([100, 99, 99, 100])))
```

> it is preferable to use an `isNaN()` to test the presence of the value of `next`, rather than a simple `if(next)`, because this test would be falsified if `next` had a value of zero.